# confusion between comparisons in elif and if statement

Tags: python

Hello can some one help me? I am using the if and elif statements but for some reason the elif statement code answers also to the if statement and the if code doesn't answer itself here is an example:

```
   #login
if(input('username=')=='hello'):
    print('continue')
elif(input('passcode=')=='goodbye'):
    print('continue')
else :
    print ('alert')
```

when I run this code this is what comes out:

```
username=hello
continue
>>>
```

Instead if I insert the passcode instead of the username this is what comes out:

```
username=goodbye
passcode=goodbye
continue
>>>
```

Worst of all is what happens if i leave the username space blank and press return:

```
username=
passcode=goodbye
continue
>>>
```

What can I do?

Comment: I dont understand the question ....

Comment: what you want to happen would be useful info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elif` statements only get evaluated if the `if` statement was false.  Follow each case line by line and you should see that what is happening is what you should expect.

Not sure how you are wanting it to work but maybe something like this

```
if(input('username=')=='hello' and input('passcode=')=='goodbye'):
    print('continue')
else :
    print ('alert')
```

Comment: ok thanks I was convinced elif statement got evaluated if if statement was true..thank you , No idea why I comprehended the elif s. incorrectly

Comment: `elif` is really short for `else if` if that helps you keep it clear

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of the if and elif are the same

Your code:

```
   #login
if(input('username=')=='hello'):
    print('continue')
elif(input('passcode=')=='goodbye'):
    print('continue')
else :
    print ('alert')
```

Try this:

```
   #login
if(input('username=')=='hello'):
    print('continue')
elif(input('passcode=')=='goodbye'):
    print('continue 2')
else :
    print ('alert')
```

Comment: thanks, but that is not the reason I got it anyways thanks to the first answer(I had no idea that elif was evaluated only if if s. was false I was convinced it was the opposite) thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. The code is doing exactly what you've coded it to do.

Is your goal to check that username and password match to be able to continue? If so, you probably want something more like this:

```
if(input('username=')=='hello'):
    print('username is OK. Continue')
    if(input('passcode=')=='goodbye'):
        print('passcode is OK. Continue')
    else :
        print('alert. Passcode is wrong.')
else :
    print('alert. Username is wrong.')
```

Comment: thanks I was convinced elif was evaluated if if s. was true...          Don't know why I mis-understood...

Answer (score 0):

See, the program does exactly what you tell it to do.

you first test if an `input()` is `"hello"`. if it is, it will print `'continue'` and skip the `elif` and the `else`.
if it is not, it will test if another `input()` equals `"goodbye"`. if it is, it will print `'continue'` and skip the `else`.
and only if the first `input()` was not `'hello'` and the second `input()` was not `'goodbye'`, it will print `'alert'`.

I think what you meant is something like:

```
   #login
if(input('username=')=='hello'):
    print('continue')
else:
    raise ValueError('alert')
if(input('passcode=')=='goodbye'):
    print('continue')
else:
    raise ValueError('alert')
```